# addthis - show correct counter for each social button

Tags: facebook, twitter, addthis

I need to show counter of each social, but this works only for facebook. For other social it shows incorrect counter.

```
   <a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter" addthis:url="{url}"></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_tweet" addthis:url="{url}"></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" addthis:url="{url}"></a>          
   <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" addthis:url="http://www.facebook.com/xxx"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

AddThis will no longer show share counts for the Twitter sharing buttons, as Twitter deprecated their share count API on November 20, 2015.
https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform
https://twittercommunity.com/t/a-new-design-for-tweet-and-follow-buttons/52791

We currently support share counts for the following services:

- Facebook
- Pinterest
- Reddit
- Delicious
- VK
- Linkedin
- Odnoklassniki

Comment: I do not need share counts, I need for example facebook page like counts,  Linkedin follows counts and so on...

Comment: <a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter" addthis:usertype="company" addthis:userid="xxx"></a> this do not work for me, the counter is 0, but the count of follower are 30.